# Отображение данных в строке запроса

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webview

Есть у меня приложение на asp net. Есть два контроллера **Board** и **Theme**. Есть представления к ним. В базе данных таблица Theme имеет внешний ключ из Board, таким образом что много Theme могут иметься в одном Board.

На странице есть список из Board, можно нажать на каждый Board и перейти на страницу со списком Theme относящему к конкретному Board. На странице с этими Theme есть кнопка "Создать для создания объекта Theme. Для этого мне нужны данные про Board.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как перейдя на страницу с Theme я смогу получить данные про Board.

Примеров моей реализации нет, но я думаю что мне нужно получить данные из строки запроса, будет у меня строка "https.../Theme/boardId=24" например и тогда я смогу получить из этой строки айдишку нужную. Но я не знаю как создать такой адрес страницы. Возможно сделать это можно иначе. Пожалуйста, помогите советами или примерами.

Comment: Если честно, то вопрос не понятен вообще, с чем проблема? Получить `Id` `Board` из `Theme`? Так у вас связь, в `Theme` так и так есть `Id` `Board`,  делайте join запрос через Include, например, если у вас EF, если не EF, то через Join руками или еще 1 select в таблицу с `Board`. Проблема с созданием страниц? Читайте: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: [Getting Started with EF 6 using MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/) - посмотрите этот туториал. Вам нужна работа со связанными данными (Related Data).

Comment: @OwDafuq, проблема в том, что созданных Theme ещё нет, они создаются на странице с Board, в этом и проблема, что чтобы создать нужно сначала получить BOard

Comment: @Elena_Gnil вообще ничего не понятно, опишите проблему нормально, что хотите сделать, что сделали, что не получается. Не пишите это в комментариях, дополняйте сам вопрос.